# Using Pointer Returned from C Library in C++

Tags: c++

I am using a library developed in C (particularly: HTK). I've made a bit modifications to source and trying to get a pointer (to beginning of a linked list) from a function.
Not to go into too much detail; say I have a struct named OutType. In my C++ code I declare:
**OutType* Out**; and pass it to some function **LName(....., OutType* Out)**
Now, in the C library, LName takes parameter Out, and calles a function named SaveH where Out is the return value (**Out=SaveH(...)**) and in SaveH, Out is malloc'ed as **OutType returnOut=(OutType*)malloc(1,sizeof(OutType));**
As far as I see, Out is perfectly malloc'ed, and in LName function I can get the address of the memory area that was allocated. But when I return to my C++ code, where I call LName and pass Out as a parameter, that parameter always has 0 as the address.
If I leave everything same, but just change SaveH so that Out is not a return value, but a parameter as **SaveH(....,OutType* Out)** and alloc that value in C++ code before passing everything is fine.
Is it normal? Is there some problem with pointer allocated in C library, using in C++ code?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing a copy of the pointer, which is why the change in the C library isn't seen in your C++ code.

Since you're already modifying the library, you should have that C function take a **pointer to a pointer**.

```
LName(....., OutType** Out)

*Out=SaveH(...);
```

Now you'll be passing the address of the C++ pointer, so your C code will be modifying the same original pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a function:

```
void Foo( int * p ) {
   p = malloc( sizeof(int) );
}
```

then when you call it:

```
int * x;
Foo( x );
```

the value of x will be unchanged, because a copy of the pointer is taken. You need a pointer to a pointer:

```
void Foo( int ** p ) {
   *p = malloc( sizeof(int) );
}
```

then:

```
int * x;
Foo( & x );
```

If this is not your problem, post some actual code that illustrates what you are asking about.